# Playing an Animation on the SkeletalMesh of a Pawn

Tags: c++, animation, unreal-engine4

In Unreal 4, I'm trying to play an animation for a Gun from a Pawn we controlled throught Virtual Reality. I tried making the same animation on a Character that has a skeletalmesh and everything went fine. Now I'm in a Pawn with the same skeletalmesh and the animation isn't playing.

```
SlickBoyMotionControllerPawn.cpp

// Function where I trigger the animation
void ASlickBoyMotionControllerPawn::Fire(ASlickBoyMotionController *Current)
{
        // Rest of the code that handle the fire of the gun

        // Current is the gun that fires (motion control)
        USkeletalMeshComponent* currentMesh = Current->GetHandMesh();
        if (currentMesh) {
            currentMesh->PlayAnimation(knockBack, false);
            currentMesh->PlayAnimation(trigger, false);
        }
}

SlickBoyMotionControllerPawn.h

UCLASS()
class SLICKBOY_API ASlickBoyMotionControllerPawn : public APawn, public IAttackable
{
    GENERATED_BODY()
public:
    // other stuff

    // Gun Anim
    UAnimSequence *knockBack;
    UAnimSequence *trigger;

    UFUNCTION()
    void Fire(class ASlickBoyMotionController* Hand);
}
```

Note that everything compiles and I don't have any error while executing the code

Comment: I forgot to put the constructor of SlickBoyMotionControllerPawn.cpp that contains the code getting the reference to the good animsequence for knockback, but it's already working fine and I'm getting the reference without a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `knockback` sequence will not play, because you are immediately overwriting the animation with `trigger`.

```
currentMesh->PlayAnimation(knockBack, false);
currentMesh->PlayAnimation(trigger, false);
```

`PlayAnimation` is a non-blocking call, the code will not wait until `knockback` has finished playing before starting `trigger`.

If you want to play two animations consecutively, use an [Animation Composite](https://docs.unrealengine.com/latest/INT/Engine/Animation/AnimationComposite/index.html)